# IOCTL Linux device driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, ioctl

Can anyone explain me,

1. What is `IOCTL`?
2. What is it used for?
3. How can I use it?
4. Why can't I define new function that does the same work as `IOCTL`?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

An `ioctl`, which means "input-output control" is a kind of device-specific system call. There are only a few system calls in Linux (300-400), which are not enough to express all the unique functions devices may have. So a driver can define an ioctl which allows a userspace application to send it orders. However, ioctls are not very flexible and tend to get a bit cluttered (dozens of "magic numbers" which just work... or not), and can also be insecure, as you pass a buffer into the kernel - bad handling can break things easily.

An alternative is the `sysfs` interface, where you set up a file under `/sys/` and read/write that to get information from and to the driver. An example of how to set this up:

```
static ssize_t mydrvr_version_show(struct device *dev,
        struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    return sprintf(buf, "%s\n", DRIVER_RELEASE);
}

static DEVICE_ATTR(version, S_IRUGO, mydrvr_version_show, NULL);
```

And during driver setup:

```
device_create_file(dev, &dev_attr_version);
```

You would then have a file for your device in `/sys/`, for example, `/sys/block/myblk/version` for a block driver.

Another method for heavier use is netlink, which is an IPC (inter-process communication) method to talk to your driver over a BSD socket interface. This is used, for example, by the WiFi drivers. You then communicate with it from userspace using the `libnl` or `libnl3` libraries.

Comment: This answer 'answers' the question partially.

Comment: the `sysfs` interface... more accessible, but now deprecated.

Comment: @Seamus only for GPIO, AFAIK, lots of other drivers use sysfs

Comment: Right... `deprecated` has several meanings. It's actually a fairly ambiguous word. And the **deprecated** `sysfs` for GPIO is a prime example: It remains in active use for GPIO - whic was the point of my comment: GPIO `sysfs` is a **deprecated** API, but it still works in a rational fashion - as opposed to `libgpiod` which is just... *bizarre*?.

Comment: Right, but `sysfs` is used for far more than GPIO (though that's likely a primary kernel driver exposure for users on something embedded like a Raspberry Pi, say). I don't think, for example, `/sys/block` is going anywhere.

Answer (score 203):

The `ioctl` function is useful for implementing a device driver to set the configuration on the device. e.g. a printer that has configuration options to check and set the font family, font size etc. `ioctl` could be used to get the current font as well as set the font to a new one. A user application uses `ioctl` to send a code to a printer telling it to return the current font or to set the font to a new one.

```c
int ioctl(int fd, int request, ...)
```

1. `fd` is file descriptor, the one returned by `open`;
2. `request` is request code. e.g `GETFONT` will get the current font from the printer, `SETFONT` will set the font on the printer;
3. the third argument is `void *`. Depending on the second argument, the third may or may not be present,
   e.g. if the second argument is `SETFONT`, the third argument can be the font name such as `"Arial"`;

`int request` is not just a macro. A user application is required to generate a request code and the device driver module to determine which configuration on device must be played with. The application sends the request code using `ioctl` and then uses the request code in the device driver module to determine which action to perform.

A request code has 4 main parts

```
    1. A Magic number - 8 bits
    2. A sequence number - 8 bits
    3. Argument type (typically 14 bits), if any.
    4. Direction of data transfer (2 bits).
```

If the request code is `SETFONT` to set font on a printer, the direction for data transfer will be from user application to device driver module (The user application sends the font name `"Arial"` to the printer).
If the request code is `GETFONT`, direction is from printer to the user application.

In order to generate a request code, Linux provides some predefined function-like macros.

1.`_IO(MAGIC, SEQ_NO)` both are 8 bits, 0 to 255, e.g. let us say we want to pause printer.
This does not require a data transfer. So we would generate the request code as below

```c
#define PRIN_MAGIC 'P'
#define NUM 0
#define PAUSE_PRIN __IO(PRIN_MAGIC, NUM)
```

and now use `ioctl` as

```c
ret_val = ioctl(fd, PAUSE_PRIN);
```

The corresponding system call in the driver module will receive the code and pause the printer.

2. `__IOW(MAGIC, SEQ_NO, TYPE)` `MAGIC` and `SEQ_NO` are the same as above, and `TYPE` gives the type of the next argument, recall the third argument of `ioctl` is `void *`. W in `__IOW` indicates that the data flow is from user application to driver module. As an example,
   suppose we want to set the printer font to `"Arial"`.

```c
#define PRIN_MAGIC 'S'
#define SEQ_NO 1
#define SETFONT __IOW(PRIN_MAGIC, SEQ_NO, unsigned long)
```

further,

```c
char *font = "Arial";
ret_val = ioctl(fd, SETFONT, font);
```

Now `font` is a pointer, which means it is an address best represented as `unsigned long`, hence the third part of `_IOW` mentions type as such. Also, this address of font is passed to corresponding system call implemented in device driver module as `unsigned long`  and we need to cast it to proper type before using it. Kernel space can access user space and hence this works. other two function-like macros are `__IOR(MAGIC, SEQ_NO, TYPE)` and `__IORW(MAGIC, SEQ_NO, TYPE)` where the data flow will be from kernel space to user space and both ways respectively.

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: I wonder if the __IOW, __IOR and __IORW functions above are correct (I mean the double underscore in some cases, in some cases not. I've never used the double underscore)... Thanks for a clear explanation!

Comment: Very well explained.. Thanks! Can you please give a small code snippet of driver side which uses this ioctl?

Comment: refer https://opensourceforu.com/2011/08/io-control-in-linux/ for example

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you. I think it is _IOWR not _IORW