# How can I use ioctl with second parameter setting 0xFACE to call a specific function?

Tags: c, ioctl

I'm a student of DLUT. Recently I read the code of the telex project.  While I am reading code, i met

```
st->client_conn = ioctl( fake_listen_sock, 0xFACE, &s_st );
```

[image]

[code link- line: 331](https://github.com/ewust/telex/blob/master/telex-station/station/net/bronnect.c)

I think ioctl is used to call the function "fake_accept_ioctl". But I don't understand what the "0xFACE" stands for here. Is there any correlation between the "0xFACE" and the function "fake_accept_ioctl"(there is no any configuration about that)? I have searched for a long time, but still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

`ioctl()` which means "input-output control" is a kind of device-specific system call. Refer [ioctl-linux-device-driver here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807846/ioctl-linux-device-driver)
Its explained really well there. Refer `ioctl()`[man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) also.